# Position from reordering in ascending order in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix in Matlab of dimension `mxn`, e.g.

```
A= [ 1     1     1;
     1     1     1;
     2     2     2;
     0     0     1]
```

I want to order the rows of `A` in ascending order and get the position of each row within this order. If I use

```
[~,~,jj] = unique(A,'rows');
```

I get

`jj=[2;2;3;1]`

What I want to get is `jj=[2;3;4;1]` (or `jj=[3;2;4;1]`), i.e. even if the first two rows of `A` are equivalent they should not be associated to the same position `jj`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [`sortrows`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html#bt8bz9j-2). This sorts your array row-based and gives you an array `index` that tells you where each row was initially.

```
[B,index] = sortrows(A);


B =

     0     0     1
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     2     2     2

index =

     4
     1
     2
     3
```

And, as @Divakar pointed out:

```
[~,out] = intersect(index,1:4);
out =

     2     3     4     1
```

Comment: Then do `[~,out] = intersect(index,1:4)`.

Comment: Or more efficient `[~,out] = sort(index)`.

Answer (score 2):

If the elements are integers only, this could be another way -

```
[~,idx] = sort(A*[0:size(A,2)-1].'*(max(A(:))+1),1) %//'
[~,out] = sort(idx) %//'
```

Sample run -

```
>> A
A =
     1     1     1
     1     1     1
     2     2     2
     0     0     1
>> [~,idx] = sort(A*[0:size(A,2)-1].'*(max(A(:))+1),1);
[~,out] = sort(idx)
out =
     2
     3
     4
     1
```